# How to run similar code in a same page

Tags: jquery, slider

I will try to be the more specific as I can.

I have a slider which uses this jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//rotation speed and timer
var speed = 4000000;
var run = setInterval('rotate()', speed);   

//grab the width and calculate left value
var item_width = $('#slidesx1 li').outerWidth(); 
var left_value = item_width * (-1); 

//move the last item before first item, just in case user click prev button
$('#slidesx1 li:first').before($('#slidesx1 li:last'));

//set the default item to the correct position 
$('#slidesx1 ul').css({'left' : left_value});

//if user clicked on prev button
$('#prevx1').click(function() {

    //get the right position            
    var left_indent = parseInt($('#slidesx1 ul').css('left')) + item_width;

    //slide the item            
    $('#slidesx1 ul:not(:animated)').animate({'left' : left_indent}, 500,function(){    

        //move the last item and put it as first item               
        $('#slidesx1 li:first').before($('#slidesx1 li:last'));           

        //set the default item to correct position
        $('#slidesx1 ul').css({'left' : left_value});

    });

    //cancel the link behavior            
    return false;

});


//if user clicked on next button
$('#nextx1').click(function() {

    //get the right position
    var left_indent = parseInt($('#slidesx1 ul').css('left')) - item_width;

    //slide the item
    $('#slidesx1 ul:not(:animated)').animate({'left' : left_indent}, 500, function () {

        //move the first item and put it as last item
        $('#slidesx1 li:last').after($('#slidesx1 li:first'));                  

        //set the default item to correct position
        $('#slidesx1 ul').css({'left' : left_value});

    });

    //cancel the link behavior
    return false;

});        

//if mouse hover, pause the auto rotation, otherwise rotate it
$('#slidesx1').hover(

    function() {
        clearInterval(run);
    }, 
    function() {
        run = setInterval('rotate()', speed);   
    }
); 

//a simple function to click next link
   //a timer will call this function, and the rotation will begin :)  
   function rotate() {
  $('#nextx1').click();
  }

  });
```

I want to have more than one slider in the same page, but I can't do it using the same code for all the sliders.

I've tried to copy the code and change the elements, like: 'slidesx1' for 'slidesx2'.
But it didn't work.

I think I have to change '$(document).ready(function() {..' for something else.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can't you give all the sliders a common class like `slider`, then replace `#slidesx1` for `.slider` ?

Comment: The code is a mess.  You should be using a function that uses a single selector, and gets the next/right buttons etc using relative selector methods like `$(this).find('that');`

Comment: It didn't work Adam. I'll upload here and you guys will see what is happening.

Comment: I know you're trying to help, but I couldn't understand, Axel. I am still learning jQuery, I'm newbie. But thx for the concern.

Comment: Haven't got time to make it 100% work, [but this might help put you in the right direction](http://jsfiddle.net/4Kjt6/). Think there's still javascript errors in there still which I haven't had time to correct.

Comment: Thx, Adam. But still not working for me. I don't know if I did something wrong, but it didn't work ):